# iOS Crash report help needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I have an app that is not yet in App store.  I have it installed on two of my local devices.  While using it on one of my devices a crash occurred.  I opened the crashlog using Devices --> Device where crash happened --> DeviceLogs and found the log with my app's name.

As shown below, I cannot decipher the method call from my app that caused the crash because it is not symbolicated **3   Pictionary                     0x0003d3c8 0x27000 + 91080** (the entire crash log is at the end of the posts)

The SO posts talk about symbolicating it using a dSYM file.  But I cannot locate this file.   I also did not do any step called Archive as mentioned din these posts.

The Build settings in my app are as follows: Deployment Post-processing --> No, Strip Debug Symbols During Copy --> No, Strip Linked Product --> yes, Strip Style --> All Symbols, Use separate strip --> No.

Any help on how I can symbolicate the crash report  or pointers to some docs that shows how to locate dsym file in apps not submitted to app store would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Date/Time:           2016-04-14 22:42:30.888 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-04-12 23:52:48.055 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  6

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x255b70d2 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33d36c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x254d0834 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 616
3   Pictionary                      0x0003d3c8 0x27000 + 91080
4   CloudKit                        0x251ac0fa __ck_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 14
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x342c6c7e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d14ce _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1458
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d0d9c _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d348c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 384
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d489e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448d98 _pthread_wqthread + 664
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343b749c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343b7290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2557c5ce __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2557ab94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x254c66cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x254c64de CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x2ce621a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
7   UIKit                           0x28c78440 UIApplicationMain + 1436
8   Pictionary                      0x0003500c 0x27000 + 57356
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x34304aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343b724c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d74ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d721e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.operation.callback
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343b74ec semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x34443554 _os_semaphore_wait + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d0312 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 354
3   CloudKit                        0x251aaf38 -[CKQueryOperation _finishOnCallbackQueueWithError:] + 196
4   CloudKit                        0x251a8832 -[CKOperation _finishInternalOnCallbackQueueWithError:] + 482
5   CloudKit                        0x251a863c -[CKOperation _handleCompletionCallback:] + 92
6   CloudKit                        0x251aae62 -[CKQueryOperation _handleCompletionCallback:] + 318
7   CloudKit                        0x251a9f54 __ck_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x342c6c80 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x342d14ce _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1458
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d0d9c _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d348e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d489e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448d9a _pthread_wqthread + 666
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.query.resultqueue
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cadf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3444bc86 pthread_kill + 58
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343698bc abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33544bb8 abort_message + 84
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3355e66a default_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33d36f0e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3355bdec std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3355b5ac __cxa_throw + 108
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33d36d46 objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                  0x254d0834 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 616
10  Pictionary                      0x0003d3ca 0x27000 + 91082
11  CloudKit                        0x251ac0fc __ck_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x342c6c80 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d14ce _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1458
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d0d9c _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d348e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x342d489e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448d9a _pthread_wqthread + 666
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x343cb9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448e14 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x34448aec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x02523000      r6: 0x36d24840      r7: 0x02521eb8
    r8: 0x15e5cd00    r9: 0x7420666f     r10: 0x00000045     r11: 0x15e5cd24
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x02521eac      lr: 0x3444bc8b      pc: 0x343cadf0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x27000 - 0x72fff Pictionary armv7  <dee81365e67e33b8a5fc5808f7ae116c> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/21B960F1-AF50-4BC7-9689-7D3953EB99AD/Pictionary.app/Pictionary
0x1fe6c000 - 0x1fe8ffff dyld armv7  <5784795b4bd43222b72f4fd81972bcfa> /usr/lib/dyld
0x24246000 - 0x24246fff Accelerate armv7  <2625f05f4ff435d9ac0994555c14bb1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x24257000 - 0x24470fff vImage armv7  <99a9ccd2fd113e9394cf8ecf6c327064> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x24471000 - 0x2454efff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <133c977bb0983e2f9ebb57d9b8d3f1b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2454f000 - 0x24812fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <a25513161f193fe7879eed04bcf64ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x24813000 - 0x24825fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7  <7ece094b2baa36f8b6a5cb90ce2e46da> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x24826000 - 0x2489afff libvDSP.dylib armv7  <21a6fbdd74303ecca17d7eee2543a039> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2489b000 - 0x248acfff libvMisc.dylib armv7  <177a0e102a2d30a0ae5fdad8d9c53926> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x248ad000 - 0x248adfff vecLib armv7  <a768aa894c4836338c1f49fe3502e7af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x24c04000 - 0x24e78fff AudioToolbox armv7  <b2b2309c919838f29ee7425c08afc165> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x24fe4000 - 0x25173fff CFNetwork armv7  <abad3f24833138f59f9dc0fb36c98487> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x25174000 - 0x251f9fff CloudKit armv7  <d876427893043060bdf39f087cc95853> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x251fa000 - 0x25259fff CoreAudio armv7  <c70889845f873b3fa644a1cae18e43b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x25275000 - 0x25292fff CoreBluetooth armv7  <b554f9cb0d073bddaa5014954011cdbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x25293000 - 0x254abfff CoreData armv7  <7e1f283e392535a6a2473ad9acb72976> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x254ac000 - 0x257dffff CoreFoundation armv7  <27e0318c286c3a39a5bd1c041ae9b9ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x257e0000 - 0x2590afff CoreGraphics armv7  <25597ae24fb135f09bce3e241c4f8a13> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x2594a000 - 0x2594cfff libCGXType.A.dylib armv7  <ca8e494d9e123749a88f428ce62a5f8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x2594d000 - 0x25957fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7  <e15dc38d22e730ff8d938f959d716d38> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x25b3f000 - 0x25b5afff libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4c67e0f45b8c3d5581df46613f75aa0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x25b5b000 - 0x25c6dfff CoreImage armv7  <fe3d317ef78334b1b7beb5c536c48101> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x25c6e000 - 0x25cc6fff CoreLocation armv7  <a1a5ebdd8a073c49b17a76939ca7cd86> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x25cf8000 - 0x25d96fff CoreMedia armv7  <b53e81ba1d973d9887783164416ec516> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x25e76000 - 0x25ed4fff CoreTelephony armv7  <7a3c12828b6b3ba1be07f753355f952b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x25ed5000 - 0x25fa2fff CoreText armv7  <2afee4d30dba3bf1b23b9627010d4150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x25fa3000 - 0x25fb9fff CoreVideo armv7  <7155300fed8b34f3b868dd2a52eb0fe2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x26227000 - 0x2642cfff Foundation armv7  <4a6c050b49d73f499fa2e138c3c0e4a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x2652e000 - 0x26583fff IOKit armv7  <aef87fa38f0239bbbe4360dd20f5edd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x26584000 - 0x267cdfff ImageIO armv7  <0814012834dd377c8100507312b7b94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x267ce000 - 0x26b18fff JavaScriptCore armv7  <000cea69d32132d68bfc20c794edbeff> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x26e10000 - 0x26e18fff MediaAccessibility armv7  <b1e0d6aa64473cb7854b51f04763a2ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x27453000 - 0x274c2fff Metal armv7  <06af7f0c67433d82910440208f1415dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x274c3000 - 0x27557fff MobileCoreServices armv7  <ae02603187a63f529fd9d449616e9f0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x280eb000 - 0x280f3fff OpenGLES armv7  <518eef6cc79733508b9212d50ea6c6e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x280f5000 - 0x280f5fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <f8a600f92e043a279b27face0467123d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x280f6000 - 0x280f8fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <d4c2cf3e626b3cb0a142c00f5a8e7ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x280f9000 - 0x280fcfff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <aa478e0af82132b5a4ccf4a94cb2522d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x280fd000 - 0x28105fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <953d0c6cc3dc3f9285f7e910e8278e79> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x28106000 - 0x28145fff libGLImage.dylib armv7  <117cb8c632eb3ee0ad5e3ff5c2601fbd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x2861b000 - 0x2877bfff QuartzCore armv7  <423d6696f1ac3b0f8cdd1bd3b9facf86> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x289b0000 - 0x289fdfff Security armv7  <31ad0c48766d3f02bab4175b11e59ce7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x28baa000 - 0x28c06fff SystemConfiguration armv7  <4057b59c404c37b7adafc0cbf6513935> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x28c09000 - 0x294b7fff UIKit armv7  <0eecf8deeadb3cc2bc8c12832e2f16c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x294b8000 - 0x2951ffff VideoToolbox armv7  <fcc7944ffb31313bb22605e5a9f535fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x29c23000 - 0x29c27fff AggregateDictionary armv7  <8b49ae4e48f734b49858c3926175d2e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x29fe2000 - 0x2a020fff AppSupport armv7  <dc25189f10f43a6c844d2ef4746a3b67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x2a162000 - 0x2a1a0fff AppleJPEG armv7  <87dace913f53351b998fa3e29daa27b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x2a1f9000 - 0x2a202fff AssertionServices armv7  <6f8ca218ed9230438f2df6a945d02924> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x2a289000 - 0x2a2a1fff BackBoardServices armv7  <8d49e141ecff3016a89fd0c307d593ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x2a2a4000 - 0x2a2d9fff BaseBoard armv7  <211e45070441303985cb96909effc670> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x2a7d5000 - 0x2a7f6fff ChunkingLibrary armv7  <9da594e2094c37df9943f2632ec861f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x2ad3a000 - 0x2ad4afff CommonUtilities armv7  <1ee7785fd9a53e7d8ac75c9a439f0326> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x2adc3000 - 0x2adc7fff ConstantClasses armv7  <f3ac20feaa813533ae7af5a57751939c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x2ae83000 - 0x2aea5fff CoreDuet armv7  <2a90ddaa96fc35eb82cf3b539a6e2b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x2aeab000 - 0x2aebbfff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol armv7  <aed0e4cb1c3d3722a880ee1a3e68f96b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x2aec2000 - 0x2aec4fff CoreDuetDebugLogging armv7  <32f761a7f9f337f4b9da8291cb523a55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x2b4d5000 - 0x2b557fff CoreUI armv7  <155c3fff49f231aa9bb3b06ee6ddef37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x2b5dd000 - 0x2b5e2fff CrashReporterSupport armv7  <a5d7521f61663732b1d02bb3e6ffca0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x2b8aa000 - 0x2b8c4fff DictionaryServices armv7  <255671d19ed63fbdb117a1173585128e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x2ba38000 - 0x2be5bfff FaceCore armv7  <b5776c59732c3a5c8c1097e3ca084aa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x2be83000 - 0x2be83fff FontServices armv7  <1db55cc4be6e3d148a364889202d824e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x2be84000 - 0x2bf59fff libFontParser.dylib armv7  <4ee8ab7c34783c9ba2043181fd75729b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x2bf5a000 - 0x2bf69fff libGSFontCache.dylib armv7  <8b0b8b06eb7338b1be0f6b0d32f7e526> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x2c04d000 - 0x2c069fff FrontBoardServices armv7  <2a2604510dee372d9544992e5ce9dd47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x2cb98000 - 0x2ce58fff GeoServices armv7  <9e9e8878a5c0331eb6571d7ac623f6b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x2ce59000 - 0x2ce69fff GraphicsServices armv7  <b851d0aa57043f9886e512ac7f181878> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x2d40e000 - 0x2d411fff IOAccelerator armv7  <b879abc90dbb39c5834b33600967a917> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x2d414000 - 0x2d41afff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <ebd64137fa2732eeb45a9eff4aad5ff7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x2d41b000 - 0x2d420fff IOSurface armv7  <dfaf5c248ad13f7facca062783742fdb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x2d421000 - 0x2d422fff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7  <9dc2544c749c30e388dc584c5ce26933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x2d4dc000 - 0x2d515fff LanguageModeling armv7  <5d13e49348b3354db09409b31177f5fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x2d58f000 - 0x2d5ecfff MMCS armv7  <fa6fa98e98e23bee967d8ca2e261d783> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x2dab5000 - 0x2dac2fff MobileAsset armv7  <67fe97f1c0f73f0da55f6273a4302848> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x2db20000 - 0x2db2cfff MobileKeyBag armv7  <3a986b00b55b38e9ada7554b059b652f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x2db59000 - 0x2db5cfff MobileSystemServices armv7  <d80584e8070331369e99d93e40f7b483> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x2e5b0000 - 0x2e5ecfff OpenCL armv7  <7087322253ac3e489b23ceae71b5c6cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x2eba8000 - 0x2ebf2fff PhysicsKit armv7  <e81bf0dec9ab3679b4907d88f7c9feb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x2ec0a000 - 0x2ec11fff PowerLog armv7  <c3abcbd661843ffd96fbbf61ce751cfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x2ef0e000 - 0x2efa4fff ProofReader armv7  <877dc9c2c0403d9daf983298b9d9cd09> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x2efa5000 - 0x2efc6fff ProtectedCloudStorage armv7  <6924532874a2325da18961ef9f4eb3c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/ProtectedCloudStorage
0x2efc7000 - 0x2efd3fff ProtocolBuffer armv7  <09518a3fe4213684864e30d7c2713a8a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x2f008000 - 0x2f076fff Quagga armv7  <5f49be2131253e828518ecfe22544f7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x2f4ff000 - 0x2f519fff SpringBoardServices armv7  <1cc5537214bd3b32a7d3a75e623bcc82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x2fb98000 - 0x2fb9bfff TCC armv7  <bbd3948d3f323aa58f2a23ab1764d508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x30adc000 - 0x30b04fff TextInput armv7  <f67e085a98fe373f8a2b0a6d4ddff973> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x30bc2000 - 0x30c84fff UIFoundation armv7  <ee212173ed843e3a8c958f53a6509a65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x30ca6000 - 0x30ca9fff UserFS armv7  <d450e0ff0bf3382a90bd449f0790c9d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x3151c000 - 0x3209bfff WebCore armv7  <0fb7c96fe7f43ddd9fa749e3bb8aa0e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3209c000 - 0x3215afff WebKitLegacy armv7  <14fccc6a183238e6ac36078d081b7b33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x32fea000 - 0x32ff2fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <76cbcf3943523557af470c72381a8c92> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33124000 - 0x3313afff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <539d3a10ddd43fbcb3e09167286986e5> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x33170000 - 0x33273fff libFosl_dynamic.dylib armv7  <fbb5d66ba2ec362f864581915d8a0572> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x3328d000 - 0x332a4fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <e31c22cd41b1360f9a4c13ecf9c90363> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x332ca000 - 0x332cbfff libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <1353dd91fbac387087c75cf8931ce39e> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3333c000 - 0x33380fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7  <99517c72776c3e748d87f3cdc0b17176> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x33490000 - 0x334b2fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <7d9ac46ec87d31328258a6f167344d0e> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x334e2000 - 0x334eefff libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <189bfe384a453f9ea396c2562f6ef521> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x334ef000 - 0x334f8fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <d63e96685df23bf69198b896ff299cf3> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x334f9000 - 0x33543fff libc++.1.dylib armv7  <85055cf4732f3667abc23ab1493c3703> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x33544000 - 0x3355ffff libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f99212723e363c78aac2d3821fa43245> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33561000 - 0x3356efff libcmph.dylib armv7  <a952fcd587a43645a32c4b0c285c78de> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x3359e000 - 0x335b7fff libextension.dylib armv7  <62b3fe124db73a7299a52c6dd980aec1> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x336e8000 - 0x336ebfff libheimdal-asn1.dylib armv7  <0a4c3a3bb4de3500b094742b6dfa6ab7> /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
0x336ec000 - 0x337d9fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <9eb49aab944934509e4a9046e22f8e80> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x337da000 - 0x33948fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0d4db0af5afe3927917f108551ecb468> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x33955000 - 0x33955fff liblangid.dylib armv7  <20a0c0e6bb983e4b97bf9665f3a8e0ea> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x33956000 - 0x33960fff liblockdown.dylib armv7  <6ca4920bb6b435baa4f4f468bec9f5c1> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33961000 - 0x33976fff liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <f9468d83c79c3c13924fbe0b67bf5825> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x33d30000 - 0x33f2afff libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d8dce7276c203150bdcbd105266b7968> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34043000 - 0x340f3fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <9eedf01990863eb4a4209fa9bb33270c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34175000 - 0x3422bfff libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1381f71041d035628a0276827dfd7996> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3422c000 - 0x3424dfff libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <2c075dfeb05732258d1859298a907763> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3424e000 - 0x3425afff libz.1.dylib armv7  <433c3df1213f3f2c8b97d2f747c7dcff> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3425b000 - 0x3425ffff libcache.dylib armv7  <289d2b8e9fd83e149062521f1890a518> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34260000 - 0x34269fff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <a182ac4b579e3a2d95f256a8a1f9e2e4> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3426a000 - 0x3426efff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <5136d1a17b22372e969d71ff8f6a5ef2> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3426f000 - 0x34275fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <05f098cd548e37348bfaaaa5a18ee4da> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34276000 - 0x342c4fff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <4f8a9b9015823f3a959dfe73f5e22957> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x342c5000 - 0x34302fff libdispatch.dylib armv7  <89da9738c8d7335a81c8c1d297533a99> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x34303000 - 0x34304fff libdyld.dylib armv7  <97e40854039630108c6898dadb83a10d> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34305000 - 0x34305fff libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8cf4f5d2baca35ed8a5f15c4af240d0c> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x34306000 - 0x34306fff liblaunch.dylib armv7  <3f9c6ce07fb13ee0a15dbf56f965061c> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x34307000 - 0x3430afff libmacho.dylib armv7  <21a119e030f23aec84234e445bc8e1ca> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3430b000 - 0x3430cfff libremovefile.dylib armv7  <b38c744ff50f3a25b8c29ee79624d6ae> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3430d000 - 0x3431efff libsystem_asl.dylib armv7  <e2aa00ff982433c784b55217febdcec1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x3431f000 - 0x3431ffff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <b11c0cd1df5038edaa021f6ee35e60c1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34320000 - 0x34382fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1f977c22653936dc99f8ecba1a4673e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x34383000 - 0x34385fff libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7  <9f5b5c4178f73bec863400eef38fb8ac> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x34386000 - 0x34387fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib armv7  <34e08e7e53ff3b018a9b58482a2fd6ae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x34388000 - 0x34394fff libsystem_coretls.dylib armv7  <19227fbb451b3c8d8e1c121b9f6e2a01> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x34395000 - 0x3439bfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <9729751e11fe32ab86cf7881fc90c7f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3439c000 - 0x343b5fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <66ea004683e432c7b62c0d1462d25618> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x343b6000 - 0x343d0fff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <143e025b6d9a3eeca173eb206b8ca401> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x343d1000 - 0x343f1fff libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <84ad54e1d9cc3e61a02d8f2b6f29309c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x343f2000 - 0x34404fff libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7  <d9a24ab278d03403b4e3f7a1a14ecf6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x34405000 - 0x34433fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <e7b6cee8e696332e8d478e98efdd5a17> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34434000 - 0x34439fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib armv7  <65d0c152ac9632d887363beec9b39f75> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x3443a000 - 0x34441fff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <efe3c04093c6360088c28a19418aeb14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x34442000 - 0x34447fff libsystem_platform.dylib armv7  <87e23da2b47437b2a3189d2c55666309> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x34448000 - 0x3444efff libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7  <8938d02473573e8ca011ba70f0c8eaf9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x3444f000 - 0x34451fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <d769f6ca52243740ac340a17e1cf6119> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x34452000 - 0x34455fff libsystem_stats.dylib armv7  <4632ee54d68d38a0994ee05a47cf708e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
0x34456000 - 0x3445bfff libsystem_trace.dylib armv7  <66a47b2a88933709b4da7836295d2a8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x3445c000 - 0x3445cfff libunwind.dylib armv7  <e52b05cc2ec13f4d9f9307d7c6393ae7> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3445d000 - 0x34478fff libxpc.dylib armv7  <3c761f5ef2fd315b895a4054cae2232e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: you can connect the real device with you development machine and run the app in debug mode. Place a exception break point you can easily figure out the issue

Comment: as you see in the crash report, some where you are  inserting an object into a mutable array, **2   CoreFoundation                  0x254d0834 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 616** may the index is wrong or the object may be nil or not a object type

Comment: Thanks @Tyson.  I am calling the insertObject at many places so knowing the exact method that is leading to the issue will help.  Also, this is not a reproducible crash.  It just happened once when I was using the app on device.  So, basically running from Xcode until the issue happens is not a viable option.

Comment: Please look at (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) ,    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html documentation may be can get an idea or the answer you need

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for you to create an archive to get dSYM's. They can also be located in your derived-data folder for example. But when you archive they're persistent unlike the derived-data. There is a simple command to locate any dSYM present on your system.

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == DEE81365-E67E-33B8-A5FC-5808F7AE116C"
```

Important for the identification is the UUID which you can decipher from the **Binary Images** - section from your crash-report.

```
Pictionary armv7  <dee81365e67e33b8a5fc5808f7ae116c>
```

You have to bring it into the UUID-scheme by hand (or that's how I do it). Make sure its *8-4-4-4-12* characters.

Executing this command will give you all the dSYM-paths that contain this specific UUID. (run it on the system that you're building your apps on)

If there are NONE you're in trouble. Then it's going to be impossible to symbolicate your crash-report.

As test to check if there are any dSYM's on your system you can run

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *"
```

Comment: Thanks, the command resulted in no output.  Do you know why the DSYMs wee not generated? Are my build settings wrong?

Comment: No dSYM's should be generated anyway. But you may have built new or wiped the derived-data since the version with this UUID has been built.

Comment: Thanks.  Lots of output but none for the app Iw ant to debug!  I think it is wrong with my build settings.  Is there any good resource that covers this practical without talking about apps in the app store?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any nice 'complete' guide to symbolicating crash-reports. It requires some research on how dSYM's and crash-reports work together. When you have this, there are guides / posts about small subsections of the whole crashreporting topic. Like the following: https://coderwall.com/p/ezdcmg/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-log-without-the-original-dsym-file